# HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext is null on Linux while non-null on Windows in ServiceStack.Core

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core, .net-core, servicestack, httpcontext

I have a simple ServiceStack project that runs on .NET Core 2.0. This works fine on Windows but fails on Linux. With the very same code (see below).

The service gets injected with an `IHttpContextAccessor` which is always non-null (Win & Linux) but its property `HttpContext` is always null on Linux and always non-null on Windows.

Minimal project to reproduce the issue:

```
using Funq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using ServiceStack;

namespace TestSS
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }

    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) { }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseServiceStack(new AppHost());
        }
    }

    public class AppHost : AppHostBase
    {
        public AppHost() : base("AO", typeof(InfoService).Assembly) { }

        public override void Configure(Container container)
        {
            var httpContextAccessor = new HttpContextAccessor();
            container.Register<IHttpContextAccessor>(httpContextAccessor);
        }
    }

    public class InfoService : Service
    {
        [Route("/info")] public class InfoRequest { }

        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

        public InfoService(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
        {
            _accessor = accessor;
        }

        public object Any(InfoRequest request)
        {
            return $"Accessor: {_accessor};\nContext: {_accessor.HttpContext};";
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding how the project is run on Linux: No reverse-proxy (nginx etc), just `dotnet build` followed by `dotnet run`, accessed locally. Nothing fancy, nothing convoluted IMHO.

---

Win:   Windows 10 Enterprise

Linux: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

dotnet --version: 2.0.2 (both platforms)

---

Further investigation:

Commenting the `IHttpContextAccessor` registration in the AppHost.Configure method has a strange effect: On Windows nothing changes, everything works as expected, on Linux an exception is thrown because the dependency cannot be fulfilled.

---

**Has anyone a solution, workaround, any information?**

Answer (score 4):

This is quite strange (to me), but it seems the fix is how you register the `IHttpContextAccessor`. This doesn't mean it is definitely the core of the issue but at least I got things working.

It certainly is a problem that the very same code, down to the last character, is behaving different on two platforms.

So the fix is to delete the two lines in the AppHost.Configure:

```
var httpContextAccessor = new HttpContextAccessor();
container.Register<IHttpContextAccessor>(httpContextAccessor);
```

and to register the `IHttpContextAccessor` in the `Startup.ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor>(new HttpContextAccessor());
```

... and this fixes my issue.

If you need, like me, to have the instance of the `HttpContextAccessor` in the `AppHost.Configure` method you can retrieve the instance in the `Startup.Configure` method and inject it, via constructor, into the AppHost instance. The retrieval is done like so:

```
var httpContextAccessor = (IHttpContextAccessor)app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IHttpContextAccessor));
```

All in all, this is strange and it there must be some kind of bug somewhere since I can get away with not registering it on Windows but not on Linux.

Comment: Any MS/.NET Core dependencies that configures the .NET Core Host should only be registered in .NET Core pipeline. This [IHttpContextAccessor 
 announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/793) shows registration examples.

Comment: Partially true, it is not registered by default when running under Linux, but it is registered by default when running under Windows :O

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you also raise this issue in the official ASP.NET Core repository?